# A pythonic way to loop a function to itself

Tags: python, arrays

How does one repeat a series of calculations on an array repeatedly feeding the data back into the loop,

so I start with an array x and have been able to make a function that performs an update of X for a single time step 'Motion'. However I am struggling to see a simple way to get this time step in a loop with the output of 'Motion' being returned to the input as X for say 50 time steps in order to see the evolution of the array.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as ran

"""----- Parameters  -----"""

L = 200
N = 100
Vmax = 50
P = [0.25]
T = 50

"""----- Initial road  -----"""

#sets all sites to empty (-1)
X = np.full((L), -1, dtype=int)
#places N cars in random positions with random  speeds
for i in ran.sample(range(L),N):
    X[i] = ran.randint(0,Vmax)

"""----- Motion of the vehicles  -----"""

def Motion(X,L,N,Vmax,P):
    #finds the index of the cars
    cars = np.where(X>-1)[0]
    #finds the distance between cars
    dist = np.append(cars[1:],cars[0]+L)-cars
    #finds the car index of cars that will crash
    crash = np.where(X[cars]>=dist)[0]
    #finds the car index of cars that are going slower than Vmax
    slow = np.where(X[cars]<Vmax)[0]
    #finds random cars to slow down e.g traffic
    random = np.where(np.logical_and(np.random.uniform(0, 1, N) < P, X[cars] > 0))[0]
    #accelerates slow cars to v+1
    X[cars[slow]] += 1
    #decelerate cars that will crash to d-1
    X[cars[crash]] = dist[crash] - 1 
    #randomly decelerate cars to v-1
    X[cars[random]] -= 1
    # Update vehicles position
    update = np.full(L, -1, dtype=int)
    update[(cars+X[cars])%L] = X[cars]
    return update
```

Not really relevant but here's the plotting code if it helps

```
"""----- Plotting  -----"""

# Plot road
def Road(X,L):
    #finds the index of the cars
    cars = np.where(X > -1)
    #locates the position of the cars 
    xaxis = np.sin(2 * np.pi * cars[0] / L)
    yaxis = np.cos(2 * np.pi * cars[0] / L)
    #plots cars on the road
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color='black', fill=False))
    plt.scatter(xaxis,yaxis, s=50, c=X[cars], cmap='Greens')
    plt.colorbar(orientation="vertical",pad=0.05).set_label('Speed')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('The open road')
    plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')
    return
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem further? You stated you do now want the output returned to the input which would be recursion. Are you looking to reproduce `Motion` x50?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I want to put the array x through the conditions of Motion 50 times putting the output of each time step back into Motion as if to simulate traffic in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're seeking but please let me know if not.

```
"""----- Motion of the vehicles  -----"""

num_iterations = 50

def Motion(X,L,N,Vmax,P,iterations=0):
    #finds the index of the cars
    cars = np.where(X>-1)[0]
    #finds the distance between cars
    dist = np.append(cars[1:],cars[0]+L)-cars
    #finds the car index of cars that will crash
    crash = np.where(X[cars]>=dist)[0]
    #finds the car index of cars that are going slower than Vmax
    slow = np.where(X[cars]<Vmax)[0]
    #finds random cars to slow down e.g traffic
    random = np.where(np.logical_and(np.random.uniform(0, 1, N) < P, X[cars] > 0))[0]
    #accelerates slow cars to v+1
    X[cars[slow]] += 1
    #decelerate cars that will crash to d-1
    X[cars[crash]] = dist[crash] - 1 
    #randomly decelerate cars to v-1
    X[cars[random]] -= 1
    # Increase counter
    iterations += 1
    if iterations >= num_iterations:
        # Update vehicles position
        update = np.full(L, -1, dtype=int)
        update[(cars+X[cars])%L] = X[cars]
        return update
    return Motion(X, L, N, Vmax, P, iterations)
```

Comment: I couldn't quite get this to work as apparently the shapes are different but thanks